# Shipping cost only if order subtotal less than specific amount else free shipping for everyone including guest.

Tags: cart, shipping, cart-rule

How to set shipping cost if cart subtotal is less than specific amount else free shipping?

This is applicable for all members even for not logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Shopping Cart Price Rules to achieve this task. Open admin->promotions->shopping cart price rules. And you should add new rule (If you installed Magento with sample data there is must be shopping cart price rule named as "free shipping" and you can use this rule).  See these reference to create free shipping rule:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes
http://www.phpro.be/news/configuring-shopping-cart-price-rules-magento-free-shipping

Comment: is it working if user is not logged in?
I tried it only work if user is logged in.

Comment: yes, of course. Check if you correctly set up Customer Groups field on rule edit page.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention,
Actually this work fine, but I want to show this shipping calculation status on cart page also.